# Understanding the direct sum of two subspaces

Tags: proof-explanation, direct-sum

I was working on this homework problem:

> Prove or give a counterexample: if $U_1, U_2, W$ are subspaces of $V$
> such that $$ V = U_1 \oplus W \quad \text{and} \quad V = U_2 \oplus W$$
> then $U_1 = U_2$.

One counterexample is:
$$ V = \mathbb{F}^2, \quad W = \{(z,z) \mid z \in \mathbb{F} \}, \quad U_{1} = \{ (x,0) \mid x \in \mathbb{F} \} , \quad U_{2} = \{ (0,y) \mid y \in \mathbb{F} \} $$

I was wondering, for this given example, why is it true that $U_{1} \oplus W = \mathbb{F}^{2}$? Can anyone provide an explanation or proof of this claim?

Answer (score 0):

$(x,y)=(x-y,0)+(y,y)$ so every vector is in the sum of $U_1$ and  $W$. Of course, $U_1 \cap W=\{0\}$.

Comment: In the first summand did you choose $x$ to be $x-y$?

Comment: @ferris I am using the fact that $x=(x-y)+y$ to write $(x,y)$ as the sum of a vector in $U_1$ and  a vector on $W$.